# SQL Server CE based applications on Windows 8

Tags: vb.net, windows-8, sql-server-ce

I'm having a problem moving running my applications on Windows 8 and 8.1 platforms. I have built few inter-connected software which use a single database file built using SQL Server CE (file is of `.SDF` format). This software works fine on Windows 7.

But whenever I try to run on Windows 8 or 8.1, it gives me error that SQL Server CE file or assembly not found.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. File name:
>   'System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'

I've tried installing SQL Server CE 4.0 on Windows 8, the setup gives error that platform is not supported. I've tried bundling the 7 DLLs of SQL Server CE along with my executable files, it still gives not found error as above.

What am I missing here. Can anyone guide?

-Faraz

Answer (score 0):

Well I get it. SQLite is the only way to go forward. I guess I'll have to change all my code and transfer my data into a new database. great.

Comment: SQL CE is fully supported om all Windows 8 platforms except Windows RT

Comment: If thats so, can you help out in finding what the problem might be. Because I have binaries which I'm trying to copy on Windows 8 platform and running them fails. SQL CE does not install on it, and I assume its not preinstalled as well. So how do I make it work on it.

Comment: See my blog post here: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2011/02/using-sql-server-compact-40-with.html